# TYPO3 11.5 how to register and call AJAX route via client JavaScript

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

Hello I am trying to call a TYPO3 Controller Action from the Frontend via JavaScript.

For Example I do have an `NewsletterController` with a `subscribeAction` like this:

```php
namespace Vendor\MyExtension\Controller;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseFactoryInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

class NewsletterController {
  /** @var ResponseFactoryInterface */
  private $responseFactory;

  public function __construct(ResponseFactoryInterface $responseFactory) {
    $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
  }

  public function subscribeAction(ServerRequestInterface $request): ResponseInterface {
    $email = htmlspecialchars($request->getQueryParams()['email']) ?? null;

    $data = [
      'email' => $email,
    ];
    $response = $this->responseFactory->createResponse()
      ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($data));
    return $response;
```

According to https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Backend/Ajax.html. I registered the route via `Configuration/Backend/AjaxRoutes.php`

```php
<?php

use \Vendow\MyExtension\Controller\Newsletter\NewsletterController;

return [
  'newsletter_subscribe' => [
    'access' => 'public',
    'path' => '/newsletter/subscribe',
    'target' => NewsletterController::class . '::subscribeAction',
  ],
];
```

So I have done this and I can see the route in the TYPO3 Backend in the `Configuration` module. So far so good. Now I want to call this route using the following JavaScript:

```js
window.addEventListener(
  "load",
  () => {
    try {
      /**
       * @type HTMLFormElement[]
       */
      const forms = document.querySelectorAll(".newsletter form");

      forms.forEach((form) => {
        form.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          const abortController = new AbortController();
          window.addEventListener("beforeunload", () =>
            abortController.abort()
          );

          const formData = new FormData(form);
          const formDataObj = {};
          formData.forEach((value, key) => (formDataObj[key] = value));
          const response = await fetch("/newsletter/subscribe", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(formDataObj),
            signal: abortController.signal,
          });

          const result = response.ok
            ? await response.json()
            : await response.text();

          console.log({ response, result });
        });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  },
  { once: true }
);
```

What could be the reason that I always get a 404 response?

best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You registered a BackendRoute which will never work in the frontend!

If you want to do AJAX in the frontend you have to implement something else:

Most easy way is to just have a plugin Action which throws a PropagateResponseException with your Response Attached. This way the Attached Response will become the main response of TYPO3 for this request. (And it disables all the template rendering.)

If you need a more stable API path (than the dynamic page-slug) you can use a Middleware to handle a certain response.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'll read up on the suggestion, you don't happen to have an example or could elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `Configuration/Backend/AjaxRoutes.php` file for your frontend use case.

If you add following TypoScript to your Root TypoScript, you can call the AJAX route via the URL `/?type=110124`. You just have to create a plugin "AjaxInterface" in the `ext_localconf.php` of your extension:

```php
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'Vendor.MyExtension'
    'AjaxInterface',
    [\Vendor\MyExtension\Controller\NewsletterController::class => 'subscribe'],
    [\Vendor\MyExtension\Controller\NewsletterController::class => 'subscribe']
);
```

TypoScript:

```
# A-J-A-X = 1-10-1-24
ajaxResponse = PAGE
ajaxResponse {
    typeNum = 110124

    config {
        debug = 0
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        additionalHeaders.10.header = Content-Type: application/json
    }

    10 = USER
    10 {
        userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
        vendorName = Vendor
        extensionName = MyExtension
        pluginName = AjaxInterface
        action = subscribe
        switchableControllerActions.AjaxInterface.1 = subscribe
    }
}
```